# Copying snapshot to another machine

Tags: linux, backup, snapshot, backup-restoration, ovf

I currently have exported an OVA of certain systems so I have a complete backup. After certain changes were made ( additional users added to LDAP for example), I created a snapshot. Would I be able to copy this snapshot to the location where my OVA is? So that I may import an OVA, and then revert to the snapshot? I am having a hard time finding a straight forward answer online or via VMwares website. Could I take the OVA, and whatever the latest snapshot of, copy to separate storage location, and then import the OVA/revert to snapshot?

I am on an entire Linux backbone and will be migrating copies/backups via command-line (bash). Not sure if that helps but gives an idea of my environment.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot "copy" a snapshot.
Creating a snapshot on a VM simply adds another "virtual disk" file. The hypervisor stops writing to the original "disk" file and from the creation of the snapshot on, it writes to the new "disk" file.
Reverting to a snapshot just deletes the added "disk" file.

In your case, you have to do a new OVA export. 
A snapshot cannot be used as a sort of "incremental" backup.